# What's the origin of "price of fish"?

Tags: idioms, expressions, etymology

I heard an old song by Scooter where he sings ["*How much is the fish?*"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+price+of+fish), realizing that it sounds so irrelevant and stupid that it might be something idiomatic with it.

Turns out it's an expression implying that the previous statement is hitting off-bounds from the current topic. Great - I learned something new.

Then, I got nerdy and wanted to learn where that expression originates from, as I was hoping for an interesting story behind it. However, I got jack when I googled it.

Anybody knows about the etymology of the expression and what it's referring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the song you refer to, so I looked up the lyrics:

> I want you back for the rhythm-attack
>   Coming down on the floor like a maniac
>   I want you back, so clean up the dish
>   By the way, how much is the fish?
>   How much is the fish?

I wouldn't necessarily assume that the lyric "how much is the fish" directly relates to the English expression "*what's that got to do with the price of fish*", for a number of reasons.

Firstly, the expression you refer to [isn't always fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_that_got_to_do_with_the...%3F). I've heard it used with eggs, rice (perhaps because it rhymes with 'price'), and *tea in China*.

Secondly, the reason for using any of the above expressions beginning with "*what's that got to do with the price of...*" is said as a response to suggest that a statement made by *someone else* is a non sequitur, or irrelevant to the matter at hand. It is not said to make a discussion irrelevant. The Scooter lyrics do not appear to be in the form of a discussion, rather they seem all to be in the *first person*.

Lastly, although I think the lyric is probably just meant to be an aberration, representing a shift in thought, as if the person is distracted, if it *is* meant to relate to a popular saying there are probably more relevant cultural references, such as the saying "[try the fish](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-root-of-the-cultural-reference-Im-here-all-week-try-the-veal)", which is sometimes tagged onto the end of a monologue to suggest the speaking style of a stand-up comedian who may be contractually obliged to recommend the special dish at the venue he is performing at. As stated, I don't think that *is* the case.

Answer (score 1):

For me (UK-based), the idiomatic standard is...

> [*What's that got to do with the price of **eggs**?*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What+does+that+have+to+do+with+the+price+of+eggs) (TheFreeDictionary)
>   A rhetorical question calling attention to a non-sequitur or irrelevant statement or suggestion made by another person. ***Primarily heard in US.*** (boldface mine)

...despite the fact that the very same dictionary defines...

> [*What's that got to do with the price of **fish**?*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/What%27s+that+got+to+do+with+the+price+of+fish%3F)
>   *A rhetorical question calling attention to a non-sequitur or irrelevant statement or suggestion made by another person. **Primarily heard in UK.***

Obviously the *specific* "thing with a price" being referenced has no particular significance, so I wouldn't take too much notice of that supposed UK/US distinction (which doesn't accord with *my* experience anyway). Have a look at the results from this Google Books search...

> [***What's that got to do with the price of...***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22What%27s%20that%20got%20to%20do%20with%20the%20price%20of%22%20-%22the%20price%20of%20eggs%22%20-%22the%20price%20of%20fish%22)

...where I've specifically *excluded* all matches where the next word is ***eggs*** or ***fish***. The first four matches there are for ***the price of air in Kansas, the price of tea in China, the price of corn, the price of bambinos in Nairobi***.

The format of the utterance is somewhat self-referential, in that the speaker calls attention to some preceding non-sequitor by introducing ***another*** one. And the fact that the "new" non-sequitor may not even be a familiar concept (speaker just makes up a "nonce-term") effectively makes the usage more "strikingly emphatic".

---

Probably the best way to "understand" this usage is to interpret it as *What you said is just as irrelevant to the conversation as is something **obviously** irrelevant (such as the price of something none of us know or care about)*. But I see no point in trying to identify a "first recorded use" for something like this - it'll probably be long lost in the mists of time.

And since Scooter is a *German* band (not even native speakers of AmE or BrE), the claimed US/UK distinction is also fairly irrelevant here.

Comment: I was hoping that the expression had an anecdotic background akin *and Bob's your uncle* but i realize that anything can be inserted as long as it's a commonly purchased item in the cultural reference. Well, too bad. As a side note for Scooter being German - while true as his origin, I believe he'd count as Brittish'ish English speaker as he's studied and lived there, hardly even visiting US, as far I'm informed.